# New Vegas - Sneak Detection

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

What is the sneak detection equation in Fallout: New Vegas?

What factors (other than perks and hiding behind things) determines if you are detected while sneaking?

I have read a lot of conflicting information about if/how these things affect sneak detection:

- armor weight
- inventory weight
- weapon weight

Is there a definitive source of information to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [many factors](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sneak_(skill)#Factors_in_successful_sneaking) involved in stealth calculation :

**Sneak Skill**, obviously. This can be improved temporarily or permanently by **perks** and **items**.

Enemy **Perception** stat : it is worth noting that a crippled head cause a -4 modifier

**Light level** : less light = more difficult to see. Be careful for your Pip-Boy light.

**Movement** : this includes looking around. The more you move, the more you are likely to be detected.

**Contact** : usurprisingly, being in direct physical contact with any target makes it aware of your position

**Sound** : you emit sound in two ways :

- Most **weapons** are noisy. Some are silenced : they don't emit sound when you use them ; that includes melee weapons and grenades (*throwing* is silent). Being attacked will always cause a NPC to enter [CAUTION] mode.
- Moving emits sound, which scales with your ***equipped* weight** ; this only includes your weapon if it is drawn. The perk "Silent Runner" negates this entirely.

**Distance**.

**Line of sight** : if you cannot be *seen*, you can only be *heard*.

Comment: The "Silent Running" perk says it only makes running less detectable while sneaking. It doesn't mention anything about equipped weight. http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Silent_Running

Comment: It does so by completely eliminating the noise you emit by moving, which is dependent on the equipped weight.

Comment: Ah, I guess that is the information I needed. Sneak seems pretty useless in New Vegas without Silent Running then. Thanks.

Comment: @theJollySin Well, just walk =D